# Populate User From Ldap Without Login in Django

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-auth-ldap

I'm using django-auth-ldap for auth backend in a Django project. But I have a problem, I can't give any permissions to a user before user once logged in. Because the user object created when user tring login to system.

I want to write a task to populate user from ldap periodically, how I can do that. I can't just login for each unpopulated user since I don't know their passwords.

Answer (score 4):

I found out I just can populate user like this:

```
    from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
    ldap_backend = LDAPBackend()
    ldap_backend.populate_user('username')
```